# Cloudflare redirect everything from domain1.com to domain2.com

Tags: redirect, cloudflare, forwarding

I would like to redirect all traffic from domain1.com (including all sub-domains) to index page of domain2.com using Cloudflare. Is it possible?
 Furthermore, is it possible to not create any A records for domain1.com for this forwarding to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, it seems I fugured it out myself and this solution works:

- Create a Page Rule where every URL that matches `*domain1.com/*` is 301-redirected to `https://domain2.com`
- Add A record where name is `domain1.com` and it points to `1.1.1.1`
- Add CNAME record where name is `*` which is an alias of `domain1.com`

Then I had to wait a couple of minutes for it all to take effect.

Comment: CNAME of `www` to `domain1.com` also works to make `www.domain1.com` also redirect.

Comment: Also a recommended IP address is `192.0.2.1` instead of 1.1.1.1 because this is test IP address not meant to be rout anywhere.